# How to fire drop even from C++ ActiveX code?

Tags: c++, mfc, vb6

I have developed VS 6.0 MFC ActiveX with drag & drop capability. The component registers itself as a drop target (with COleDropTarget.Register()) and all drag & drop process works normally -- component captures the drop event in C++ code like:

```
BOOL CMyGraphCtrl::OnDrop(CWnd *pWnd, COleDataObject *pDataObject, DROPEFFECT dropEffect, CPoint point)
{   //  Control comes to this line after mouse is released when dragging
}
```

The next step is to inform the container VB6 application with some event that text or files are dropped in ActiveX. New event OnMyDrop() is introduced in ActiveX interface and I expect that event will be invoked from ActiveX code like:

```
BOOL CMyGraphCtrl::OnDrop(CWnd *pWnd, COleDataObject *pDataObject, DROPEFFECT dropEffect, CPoint point)
{
    OnMyDrop(pDataObject, point.x, point.y);
}
```

How the first OnMyDrop() parameter must be declared (LPUNKNOWN? VARIANT?) that COleDataObject can be passed there? I expect that this event will be mapped in VB6 as:

```
Private Sub MyGraph_OnMyDrop(Data As DataObject, X As Single, Y As Single)
   If Data.GetFormat(vbCFFiles) Then
      ' Do something
   End If
End Sub
```

Thank you,
Sal

Comment: VB6 rather likes working with `IDispatch`.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt Thanks. I have tried the OnMyDrop() event IDispatch notation in C++ as:
    "void OnMyDrop(LPDISPATCH Data, float x, float y)",
but it is mapped to
    "Private Sub MyGraph_OnMyDrop(ByVal Data As Object, X As Single, Y As Single)"
in VB6 and then it crashes. How can I get Visual Basic DataObject in this event, not an Object?

Comment: You don't have a VB6 DataObject, you have a C++ `COleDataObject`.  Both implement the same COM interface but that doesn't make them 100% interchangeable.  You have to find out what COM calls a VB6 DataObject.  So, make a VB6 DLL that uses `DataObject` and then open it with the OLE TypeLib Viewer to see the matching IDL.

Comment: BTW, have you tried simply `IDataObject*`?  Note that you can't pass your `COleDataObject` through COM.  It isn't a COM object, it is a smart pointer to a COM object.  Use `COleDataObject::Detach()` to get the COM object.